# Dynamic population of dropdown list added to Eclipse toolbar within Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, swt

The subject topic seems easy enough in other areas of Eclipse plugin development such as ones own toolbars on dialogs. In this instance, I've added a drop-down to the main toolbar within my perspective, via the plugin.xml as follows

```
<menuContribution
        locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
    <toolbar
            id="com.company.ui.toolbar2">
            // other items removed for clarity

        // following is a drop-down
        <command
                commandId="com.company.ui.mydropdown"
                label="%config.label.default"
                icon="icons/myIcon.png"
                style="pulldown">
            <visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
                <reference definitionId="com.company.ui.visibilityTester"/>
            </visibleWhen>
        </command>
    </toolbar>
</menuContribution>
```

I've got the command defined elsewhere and a handler in the plugin.xml file which currently works as it would for a button.

However, the dropdown is unpopulated. I need a way to dynamically populate for the following reasons:

1. Dropdown list content comes from an API
2. One of the list items (or clicking the list like a button) launches a dialog that can edit the list
3. Closing the dialog means the list needs to be refreshed (rebuilt) and the selected/active item re-evaluated

I also need to be able to hook a user selecting a different list item and calling my API.

I've noticed other examples online try and create the dropdown differently, but I have knowledge gaps about how these wire up. For example, where a Contribution is used, it is not always clear how this links back to the particular definition in the plugin.xml file. I have not seen an example that shows this clearly.

I need to support Eclipse 4.4.2 and later, so contemporary Eclipse 4 examples may not be apt.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to add a control to the toolbar section of the menu contributions like:

```
<menuContribution locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
    <toolbar id="com.company.ui.customToolbar">
        <control
            class="com.company.ui.MyDropDownContribution"
            icon="icons/yourIconHere.png"
            label="%config.label.default">
            id="theDropdown">
            <visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
                <reference definitionId="com.company.ui.isMyTestCaseSatisfied"/>
            </visibleWhen>
        </control>
    </toolbar>
</menuContribution>
```

And then to implement a contribution class extending WorkbenchWindowControlContribution. My simplified code, which includes the means to launch an EXE from one of the list items (and could be re-used to do something else), essentially is:

```
public class MyDropDownContribution extends
        WorkbenchWindowControlContribution {

    private Combo dropdownlist;

    private boolean listenerAdded = false;
    private String currentlySelected = "Item 1";
    private String[] listOfItems = new String[]{ "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Launch my EXE" };

    private final SelectionAdapter selectionListener = new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            if(e.widget instanceof Combo) {
                // if the selection is currentlySelected, do nothing
                if(dropdownlist.getText().equals(currentlySelected)) {
                    return;
                }

                //if the selection is to launch 'something', do that
                if(dropdownlist.getText().equals("Launch my EXE")) {
                    launchExecutable();
                } else {
                    // otherwise, a new item has been selected, do what you need to
                }
            }
        }
    };


    private void launchExecutable() {
        // place your code to launch your EXE here - you could do some other special case, not just launch EXE
    }


    @Override
    protected Control createControl(Composite parent) {
        Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout glContainer = new GridLayout(1, false);
        glContainer.marginTop = 0;
        glContainer.marginHeight = 0;
        glContainer.marginWidth = 0;
        container.setLayout(glContainer);
        GridData glReader = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false, 1, 1);
        glReader.widthHint = 150;
        dropdownlist = new Combo(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.READ_ONLY
                | SWT.DROP_DOWN);
        dropdownlist.setLayoutData(glReader);
        populateDropdown();
        toggleComboListener();
        return container;
    }

    private void toggleComboListener() {
        if(listenerAdded) {
            dropdownlist.removeSelectionListener(selectionListener);
        } else {
            dropdownlist.addSelectionListener(selectionListener);
        }
        listenerAdded = !listenerAdded;
    }

    public void populateDropdown() {
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().syncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dropdownlist.setItems(new String[]{});
                for(String itemName : listOfItems) {
                    dropdownlist.add(itemName);
                }
                dropdownlist.setText(currentlySelected);
            }
        });
    }
}
```